# Different behaviour when NSMenuitem is clicked vs Key Equivalent

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

All,

I have an odd one. I have a menu item that will directly lead to open a sheet (via beginSheet(,completionHandler:). 
All is fine when I use it through the menu. But when I use the keyboard shortcut the resulting sheet behave differently.

- **Menu click behaviour:** I show an NSOutline that works nicely. I can click etc.
- **Keyboard shortcut behaviour**: the NSOutline cannot get any mouse events. Clicking doesn't lead to anything.

Interestingly enough, the closing button on the sheet is always working correctly.

Any ideas how I managed to get into this situation?

Many thanks in advance!

[image: the sheet that I refer to]

Comment: my best guess that it is either about been focus at time of creating the sheet or about a different time of releasing temporary data in the call stack (the outline delegate might be released), but all tests in both directions didn't make any change to this behaviour.

Comment: Storyboard? Popovers behave weird when shown as popover, presenting the viewcontroller as popover works ok.

Comment: Thanks Willeke, but this is a sheet panel, not a popover. I do believe that popover would indeed work better, but it's not the graphical style I want to use here.

Comment: Maybe a sheet has the same problems. If this is a storyboard, you could present the viewcontroller as sheet instead of using `beginSheet`.